# How to check out a subversion tag in jenkins?

Tags: svn, jenkins

I have a subversion structure as below:

```
             MyProject
                 |----------> Branch
                 |----------> Tags
                               |----->Release1
                               |----->Release2
```

Using "This build is parameterized" option i added "List sub version tags" parameter .

In the Repository URL i gave the URL till " MyProject". 
When I clicked on "Build now" option I got a drop down box listing Branch and tags folders so I can select either Branch or tags to be built by Jenkins.

But what I want is along with the Branch and tags folders I also need Release1 and Release2 folders to be listed in the dropdown.

Is it possible to do that way?

Comment: I can tell it's possible. But it seems to depend on Repository settings. One of my repos shows the behavior you want, another show the behavior your described. For now not sure what it depends on.

Answer (score 0):

The following plugin will do that: **[Dynamic Extended Choice parameter](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Dynamic+Extended+Choice+Parameter+plugin)**. I have not personally used that, so refer to the documentation on that page for details.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.This makes use of properties file to get the names of branches and tags. We have 100s of projects so I dont think its feasible.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a tagging scheme that supports it, you should be able to set the "Tags filter" to only allow the tags you are interested in.

For instance, on one project, our SCM plan and tag name convention specifies that releases may only be built from tags that contain "Promoted_Integration_".  To enforce this, we use a "Tags filter" of ".*Promoted_Integration_", and the user can only see valid tags.

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be a bug in the plugin. On top level of your repo you need the three folders

- trunk
- tags
- branches

Otherwise the plugin comes into trouble